# CMSMS - CGBlog how to output html for all but last entry?

Tags: content-management-system, smarty, smarty3

I'm new to CMSMS and am using CGblog where I have a listing template and everything is working fine except that I need to stop an HR tag from displaying on the last item. Can't figure out the correct way to code this.

**CMS Made Simple™ 1.11.10 “Pinzon”**

```
{foreach from=$items item=entry}
<div class="CGBlogSummary">

      <article>

        <h3><a href="{$entry->detail_url}">{$entry->title|escape}</a></h3>
        <p style="font-size: 12px;">{if $entry->author}Written by <a href="">{$entry->author}</a>{/if}{if $entry->postdate} on {$entry->postdate|cms_date_format}.{/if}</p>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            {if isset($entry->extra)}
                <div class="CGBlogSummaryExtra">
                    {eval var=$entry->extra}
              { {cms_module module='Uploads' mode='simpleurl' upload_id=$entry->extravalue} }
                </div>
            {/if}
            {if isset($entry->fields)}
              {foreach from=$entry->fields item='field'}
                 <div class="CGBlogSummaryField">
                    {if $field->type == 'file'}
                      <img src="{$entry->file_location}/{$field->value}"/>
                    {else}
                      {$field->name}:&nbsp;{eval var=$field->value}
                    {/if}
                 </div>
              {/foreach}
            {/if}
          </div>
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            {if $entry->summary}
              {eval var=$entry->summary}            
            {else if $entry->content}
                {eval var=$entry->content}
            {/if}
            <p><a href="{$entry->detail_url}">Read more...</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>

      <hr /><!-- this should not be output on the final iteration of the loop-->

</div>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple change this line:

```
<hr /><!-- this should not be output on the final iteration of the loop-->
```

into

```
{if not $entry@last}<hr />{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use syntax as such:

`<hr {if $entry@last} style='display:none' {/if} />`

(hides the hr using css if its the last entry), quick and dirty though!

Comment: That works, but is not ideal. Better would be to have it not output at all.

Comment: Marcin Nabiałek has the correct answer, just needed a "not" after the "if" :)